# Xamarin.Forms bundle assemblies into native code

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created an Android App with Xamarin.Forms. I used "SKD and User Assemblies" for linking and with some dummy usage of classes (to fool linker) and using the

```
[Android.Runtime.Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
```

annotation I could run my app without problem and reduce apk size from about 50 MB to 19 MB. But 19 MB is still too much! So I used "Bundle assemblies into native code", build and archive is OK and my apk size is about 6 MB now. But when I open the app, It closed immediately without any error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the contents of your `.apk`, if you are missing the `libmonodroid_bundle_app.so`, if so there are two basic possibilities.

- Your Visual Studio (Mac or Windows) installation is not a valid Enterprise license or is a Community/Profession license and the `mkbundle` step is not being executed

  ```
   IMHO: This should always be an MSBuild error/failure if 
     BundleAssemblies is true in your `.csproj` but you do not 
     have the correct license but it is currently not.
  ```
- MSBuild is failing on the Android NDK building of the shared library that contains your CIL assemblies.

This issue is on bugzilla and was *fixed* in the 7.2.0 release, but I've seen it come back up in some 7.5 / 8.x releases.

The issue with this can be a **silent failure** and thus not seen by MSBuild and thus an APK is produced with no `libmonodroid_bundle_app.so` file.

- Review issue [48678](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=48678)
- Test outside of the Visual Studio IDE using MSBuild from the cmd-line. Pass the `/t:PackageForAndroid` to a release configuration and see if you are getting a clean `_BuildApkEmbed` task:

Clean/working:

```
    _BuildApkEmbed:
      [mkbundle stderr]
     [cc stderr]
     [LD] X:\Docker\android-sdk-windows\ndk-bundle\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm
      -linux-androideabi-ld.exe --shared obj\Release\bundles\armeabi-v7a\temp.o obj\Release\bundles\armeabi-v7a\assemblies.
      o -o obj\Release\bundles\armeabi-v7a\libmonodroid_bundle_app.so -L X:\Docker\android-sdk-windows\ndk-bundle\platfo
    rms\android-14\arch-arm\usr\lib -lc -lm -ldl -llog -lz
      [ld stderr]
```

Broken/error:

```
Platform header files for target Arm and API Level XX was not found. Expected path .....
```

If that is the case, (re)install your Android NDK:

- https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html

The last failure, not related to your problem, but possibly others.

A complete crash and restart of Visual Studio 2017 during the archive process.

If you are missing files in your Android NDK installation, have an corrupt installation or the wrong version. Also some versions from Google do not have any **include** directories (?!?!) but do have the arch `lib` directories and without the header files, the Xamarin.Android MSBuild process hangs VS and causes a crash/restart.

Comment: @ShahramShobeiri no problem, you have the wrong license issue or the NDK problem?

Comment: @ShahramShobeiri yea, that is why I said that type of problem should be an MSBuild failure so you are aware of it immediately.

Comment: I guess it was NDK problem because after updating visual studio 2017 (to 15.4.0) the problem solved and now my apk is about 10 MB and the app works like a charm.

Comment: Could you please point me where is the option "Bundle assemblies into native code" on VS for Mac version 7.3.2? Thanks.

Comment: @rraallvv Are you running an `Enterprise` license of VS4M?

Comment: Community version, I added those options directly in the project Droid.csproj file https://stackoverflow.com/q/48025885/1436359

Comment: @rraallvv the assemblies will be "zipped" bundled into `libmonodroid_bundle_app.so` so they can be inflated at runtime.