# How to build a Xamarin.Android project without managed executables?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm tinkering with **Xamarin.Forms** on **Visual Studio Community for Mac** version 7.3.2

What I'm trying to accomplish is to convert all managed code to native executables using these options in **MyApp.Droid.csproj**:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>false</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
  <AotAssemblies>true</AotAssemblies>
  <EnableLLVM>true</EnableLLVM>
</PropertyGroup>
```

`EmbedAssembliesIntoApk` does embed the assemblies into the apk so I've set it to false, because those are precisely what I want to get rid of.

I've also set `AotAssemblies` and `EnableLLVM` to true so the managed code is AOT compiled and converted to native code.

Those options build a signed apk with the `lib/` folder containing the files below and no assemblies folder, which is what I want.

```
lib/
  armeabi-v7a/
    libgdbserver.so
    libmono-profiler-log.so
    libmonodroid.so
    libmonosgen-2.0.so
```

The problem is that if I clear the application data on the device and try to run the app again it won't start giving me some error saying *'no assemblies found'* or *'conflicts between different versions of the same assembly'*

Is it possible to build and ship a **Xamarin.Forms** application for **Android** without any managed assemblies, but only native executables?

**Update:**

I tried Xamarin Studio and it adds the option `BundleAssemblies`, so the project setting are as follows but Xamarin fails build the target:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
  <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
  <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
  <AndroidLinkMode>Full</AndroidLinkMode>
  <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
  <AotAssemblies>true</AotAssemblies>
  <EnableLLVM>true</EnableLLVM>
  <BundleAssemblies>true</BundleAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

With those option on Visual Studio I get this executables:

```
lib/
  armeabi-v7a/
    libmonodroid_bundle_app.so
    libmonodroid.so
    libmonosgen-2.0.so
```

plus a bunch of files `something.dll.so`

Comment: `EmbedAssembliesIntoApk` would "convert" your assemblies (.dll) to be invoked in a native shared library (.so).

Comment: @JonDouglas Do you mean `EmbedAssembliesIntoApk`set to true? I'll give it a try.

Comment: @JonDouglas with `EmbedAssembliesIntoApk` set to true I get `libmonodroid_bundle_app.so` and a bunch of `.dll.so` files. Do you know if those dependencies could be merged into the main executable, maybe using `mkbundle`. Does VS support that option?

Comment: What is the context of "main executable" in this scenario?